# Bernoulli vs Adaboost GBM?

Tags: r, classification, gbm

I don't really understand the difference in practical terms of distribution = Adaboost or bernoulli

```
   library(MASS)
   library(gbm)
   data=Boston
   data$chas = factor(data$chas)
   ada_model = gbm(chas~ . , data, distribution ='adaboost')
   bern_model = gbm(chas ~ . , data, distribution = 'bernoulli')
   ada_model
   bern_model
```

I don't understand why bernoulli doesn't give any results?  I guess I have a fundamental mis-understanding of how this works?

I'm looking for:
1.  explanation why bernoulli doesn't work.  I thought documentation said this can be used for classification?
2.  if they can both be used for classification, what are the practical differences?

Comment: Your code works fine for me if I comment out line 4.

Comment: yes, but then it is no longer classification?

Answer (score 0):

Bernoulli is breaking for you because the `factor` call recodes the 0/1s to 1/2s:

```
> str(factor(data$chas[350:400]))
Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
```

Comment: How do I fix this then?  I can't seem to change them to 0s and 1s?

Answer (score 0):

```
> str(data$chas)
 int [1:506] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
> sum(data$chas==0) + sum(data$chas==1)
[1] 506
```

There are currently 506 integers which are all either zero or one.  Nothing to do.  Remove line 4 as @Neal Fultz recommended in his original comment and explained in his answer.  If you want to explicitly bound the variable to {0,1}, you can use `as.logical` and your code becomes:

```
library(MASS)
library(gbm)
data=Boston
data$chas = as.logical(data$chas) # optionally cast as logical to force range into 0 or 1
ada_model = gbm(chas~ . , data, distribution ='adaboost')
bern_model = gbm(chas ~ . , data, distribution = 'bernoulli')
ada_model
bern_model
```

---

Reading between the lines a little, I'm guessing that your real problem is that your production dataset has values other than {0,1}.  Casting them to logical will convert them to `TRUE` (1), and you're ready to go.  If that's not what you want, then use this to find them and examine them case-by-case:

```
which((data$chas != 0) & (data$chas != 1))
```